# JavaScript WYSIWYG implementation

Tags: javascript, implementation, wysiwyg

I want to write a very simple WYSIWYG editor, but i don't understand how do they work :(
I've tried to read sources of tinyMCE but stuck in all those classes and functions.
As I know they're creating iframe then do some black magic there and everything works.
The question is: what do those editors do with iframe so it becomes editable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords are `contentEditable` and `designMode`.

Good sources to get started:

- [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla (MDC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla)
- [element.contentEditable in Mozilla (MDC)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.contentEditable)
- [contentEditable in IE (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537837%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

very simple means you want little extension? In such case, you will like http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/

Its constructor is really simple, but not good for extension works.
You can search JQuery. I think there's huge amount of HTML editor or rich text editor available.
By the way, the HTML editor inside Extjs is the worst thing I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Google released yesterday an open source editor:
http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-closure-library-editor.html

A quick look at it shows an IFRAME with the BODY tag with the attribute: contentEditable